Wiggly/wavy shadows in Eevee
I am trying to achieve a toon shadow effect but when I hit render, the shadows look wavy and jagged as well as being soft. Is there a way to fix this, I also notice that these significant shadow acne which I've never experienced before but I think this is due to wanting hard shadow values for a cartoon effect.

